# Adding a list of integer to different slices of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like so below:

```py
   active   idx
0   nan     0
1   20.0    0
2   32.0    0
3   nan     1
4   38.0    1
5   24.0    1
6   nan     2
7   33.0    2
8   44.0    2
9   59.0    2
10  nan     3
11  17.0    3
12  15.0    3
13  9.0     3
```

I also have a series like so:

```py
idx
0     3
1     3
2     4
3     4
Name: active, dtype: int64
```

And I also have a list like so:

```py
list = [[4.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0]]
```

I need to broadcast the list element who's position corresponds to the idx in the first data frame from the nth+1 number of values in the data frame so we ignore the np.nan that is shown at the start of every new idx.

So for idx = 0, I do a lookup in the second series and see for the first 2 values I need to broadcast the first element that is [4.0, 4.0] the values after the nan, so no number should be added to the np.nan

So it should come out like so:

```py
   active   idx
0   nan     0
1   24.0    0
2   36.0    0
3   nan     1
4   40.0    1
5   27.0    1
6   nan     2
7   34.0    2
8   44.0    2
9   60.0    2
10  nan     3
11  17.0    3
12  15.0    3
13  8.0     3
```

I know I can loop through but that's not the most optimised way, I've tired grouping by and applying functions but Im struggling with broadcasting the list to the values.

Comment: Does it work to do `df.active = df.active + np.concatenate(list)`, or is there more to the question that I am not seeing?

Comment: hi @ProfessorPantsless, I've updated the question I forgot to include some rows, I want to add the list to the corresponding idx from n+1 so nothing gets added to the value with nan in it.

Comment: `df.active[~df.active.isna()] += np.concatenate(list)`? This assumes list corresponds nicely with the non null values in the column of interest.

Comment: perfect legend, this helps - I was trying to be way to complicated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your list is already in the correct order, you can filter out the `nan` values from the dataframe and do the operation on that. You can use `numpy.concatenate` to flatten the list. Assuming your dataframe is named `df`:

```
df.active[~df.active.isna()] += np.concatenate(list)
```

Would also recommend using a different variable name than `list` in python.